# how to test iOS PayPal checkout not native eligible use case

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

I am using [paypalcheckout-ios](https://github.com/paypal/paypalcheckout-ios) for adding payment to my app.

Basing on the paypal documentation it can work in two different mode native or not native (web based).

The switching between the two mode is strictly related to the merchant and/or customer country.

https://developer.paypal.com/limited-release/paypal-mobile-checkout/

Native mode:
[image: Native mode]

Non native mode (web fallback)
[image: Non native]

How can I test the web fallback for not native eligible use case on iOS?

With Android SDK it can be done setting true the shouldFailEligibility in SettingsConfig but I am not able to find anything similar in iOS sdk.

```
class SettingsConfig(

/**
 * Enables Checkout SDK logs. It is recommended to disable this when releasing to production.
 */
val loggingEnabled: Boolean = false,

/**
 * This should remain false in production!
 *
 * Enabling this will cause eligibility to always fail. This provides a way to test web
 * fallback.
 */
val shouldFailEligibility: Boolean = false
)
```

Comment: Have you tried with [test creditcards](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/payflow/payflow-pro/payflow-pro-testing/)?

Comment: @ToseefKhilji the checkout ui has loaded before the credit card request, since it is the place for providing credit card info :-) so test credit cards are not useful for testing this scenario. I guess that it is the reason for the shouldFailEligibility flag in Android

Comment: Better create issue at Github, so they can work on that flag.

Comment: done! https://github.com/paypal/paypalcheckout-ios/issues/113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 0.112.0 ([see release note](https://github.com/paypal/paypalcheckout-ios/releases/tag/0.112.0)) a specific flag was added to CheckoutConfig. It can be used for testing the web fallback for not native eligible use case on iOS

```
CheckoutConfig.showWebCheckout = true
```